# How to get all the filename and filesize in current directory in Python

Tags: python

Hi I am working with a little script. I try to print all the files in the current directory and store the `filename:filesize` as `key:value` pairs to the `size_dir`.

```
from os import listdir,environ
from sys import argv
from os.path import isfile,join
import os

size_limit = argv[1]
my_path = "./"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, f))]
sizes = []
size_dir = {}
print size_limit
for item in onlyfiles:
    print type(os.path.getsize(my_path+item))
    if os.path.getsize(my_path+item) < size_limit:
        size_dir[item] = os.path.getsize(my_path+item)
print(size_dir)
```

I run this program in my terminal by:

```
python THISFILENAME.py 300
```

As I expected, the size_limit received 300 from my input command. In the for loop, I set a if-statement to check whether the file exceeds the size_limit, if not then we add the file to the size_dir.
However, when I print the size_dir out, I find that size_dir contains every file in my current directory, and this is not what I expected.

Result:

```
{'dir_print.py': 825, 'argvdemo.py': 215, 'formatter.py': 404}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `size_limit` be `argv[2]`? I thought `argv[0]` was the command itself, and then `argv[1]` was the first argument.

Comment: It should be argv[1], and I used print to check it. The first "python" is used to run python program.

Comment: The problem appears to be it's not properly checking if the size is under the limit in your if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you read `size_limit` from the command line arguments, it's read as a string, instead of as an integer. You are then comparing a number to a string in the line:

```
if os.path.getsize(my_path+item) < size_limit:
    ...
```

When you compare a numeric type with a non-numeric type in Python 2.x, the numeric type is always less than the other type in the comparison, so the line above will *always return true*. In Python 3.x, your comparison would have raised a `TypeError`.

You should cast the `size_limit` to an integer to make it work properly (notice the line where `size_limit` is assigned).

```
from os import listdir,environ
from sys import argv
from os.path import isfile,join
import os

# Here I convert the argument you get to an integer
size_limit = int(argv[1])

my_path = "./"
onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(my_path) if isfile(join(my_path, f))]
sizes = []
size_dir = {}
print size_limit
for item in onlyfiles:
    print type(os.path.getsize(my_path+item))

    if os.path.getsize(my_path+item) < size_limit:
        size_dir[item] = os.path.getsize(my_path+item)
print(size_dir)
```

Comment: In Python 3.x, the comparison of a string to an integer with `<` will raise an exception instead.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Thanks - not as familiar with Python 3.x behavior, but I updated my post with your information for clarity.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Oh I see why I don't have a sense of it... I start my python life in python 3.... Thanks for telling.

Answer (score 6):

Here is what I got for you with the lowest amount of lines I could think of:

This program:

1. Is dynamic, and will work in any directory you put it in.
2. Can convert sizes to MB and KB very easily in the Calculating for-loop.
3. Only imports 1 library.
4. Ends with a dict of all stat info organized by ['Filename']: stats
   .

   ```
   import os
   thePath = os.getcwd()
   theFiles = list(os.listdir(thePath))

   theDict = dict()
   for something in theFiles: #Calculate size for all files here. 
       theStats = os.stat(something)
       theDict[something] = theStats

   for item in theDict:
       print("The File: {:30s} The Size: {:d} Bytes".format(item,theDict[item].st_size))
   ```

**Sample output:**

```
The File: .idea                          The Size: 272 Bytes
The File: getFileSizes.py                The Size: 319 Bytes
The File: testMissingItems.txt           The Size: 201 Bytes
The File: testVariablesFromMethods.py    The Size: 1372 Bytes
The File: .DS_Store                      The Size: 6148 Bytes
The File: detectSpace.py                 The Size: 1180 Bytes
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert your size limit into an `int`:

```
size_limit = int(argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Name:

```
import os
nameList = os.listdir("path")
```

Size (Assuming you already have the "nameList":

```
statinfo = os.stat(nameList[index])
fileSize = statinfo.st_size
```